# X-Content-Type-Options = nosniff workaround

Tags: javascript, .net, iis-6

I've added X-Content-Type-Options header in my web.config, which, true to it's nature, is not loading a script because `response.contentType` is "`text/html`".

Now, I'm explicitly modifying the response as:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
```

Debugger even hits these lines of code but in the end `ContentType` is "`text/html`".

How do I modify the `ContentType`?

P.S. I'm hosting this website on IIS 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add `Response.Flush()`:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
Response.Flush();
```

**Edit:**
As you are using MVC, you should set the content type in the view, not the controller, something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" ContentType="text/javascript" %>
```

Or Razor:

```
@{ Response.ContentType = "text/javascript"; }
```

Comment: Added Response.Flush() but now getting _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <_ error

Comment: And when I checked in developer tools, the 'ContentType' is still "text/html"

Comment: @NoviceCoder Sounds like a typo. Where on your page do you have the above code? At the very top, between <% %> ?

Comment: No, actually I'm adding a script tag to redirect to that code.

Comment: This is my script tag

<script src="~/ResourceScript" type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: And in ResourceScript you have the `Response.Clear` etc?

Comment: Is the `Response` code the first thing in ResourceScript? Can you post ResourceScript? If you call ResourceScript direct in browser like http://localhost/ResourceScript what do you get now?

Comment: ResourceScript is actually a controller,

public class ResourceScriptController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /SomeScript/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
            Response.Flush();
            return View();
        }
 }

Comment: Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent

Comment: Ah-ha! In that case, you need to set the content type in the View. I will update answer.

Comment: Did you remove the three Response lines from the controller? You don't need them there as well.

Comment: Yes, now the problem is, whole page's ContentType has been changed. How do I change the content type of a particular request's response?

Comment: That's odd. I'd check there aren't any other places where the javascript content type is being set - search your codebase - perhaps there's a ghost from something you tried earlier that's setting it on the page? (You don't use the same View for the page as for ResourceScript do you?)